# User authentication across client user

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-1.2

My Application in zend framework, symfony,doctrine.

In my web Application have multiple clients which have it's their entities like product and  product related to other entities. Below is my problem :

**User Table(clients) :**

```
id       Name 
----------------
1        A
2        B
```

**Product Table :**

```
id       Name       
-------------
1        Product-1
2        Product-2
3        Product-3
```

**UserProduct Table :**

```
id       user_id   product_id
1        1         1
2        1         2
3        2         3
```

Client 'A' go to edit product after login, Url : `xyz.com/product?id=1`
Now client 'B' go to edit product after login, Url : `xyz.com/product?id=1`

So client 'B' should not edit product id = 1.

**Is it possible to make in general function?**

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can able to restrict the client 'B' should not edit product id = 1. You can use Joins for getting record form table. You have to maintain `user_id` in session

```
SELECT * FROM product p LEFT JOIN userproduct up ON (p.id == up.product_id) WHERE p.id = '1' AND up.user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'] ;
```

This won't allow to view other clients products to current client.

Comment: You are right but I don't to make query every time. I have number of models in my application so I want to restrict by generalize. Like ACL will restrict user to access our controller/action etc. but not restrict such like this issue.
understood what my issue?